# Kubectl describe returns 404 for Ingresses

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress

I reinstalled my system today and since than i can not access my Ingresses anymore with `kubectl describe`, `get` works fine and returns the expected Ingresses.

```
kubectl describe ingresses
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

This is the response i get if i run `describe` with `-v 8`

```
GET host:443/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/ingress-rule
Request Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
    Accept: application/json, */*
    User-Agent: kubectl/v1.15.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e8462b5
Response Status: 404 Not Found in 14 milliseconds
Response Headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 174
    Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 12:30:05 GMT
Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"the server could not find the requested resource","reason":"NotFound","details":{},"code":404}
```

This is the kubectl version result

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.7", GitCommit:"6f482974b76db3f1e0f5d24605a9d1d38fad9a2b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T02:41:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Hi, can you run `kubectl version ` hopefully both client and server are not having compatibility issue

Comment: Hi @Joachim, did downgrading the kubectl resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with different version of kubectl client and server. you need to downgrade your kubectl client to the 1.12

In k8s v.15 **ingress** is part of the group `networking.k8s.io` before it was in the `"extensions/v1beta1"` group

> Ingress resources will no longer be served from extensions/v1beta1 in v1.19. Migrate use to the networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 API, available since v1.14. Existing persisted data can be retrieved via the networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 API.[k8s CHANGELOG-1.15.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md)

Answer (score -2):

Try to run

```
kubectl get ingress
```

If you have ingress defined in namespace other than default use below:

```
kubectl get ingress -n <NSNAME>
```

once you have list of ingress resources, you can describe using:

```
kubectl describe ingress <IngressName> -n <Namespace>
```